# Convert to LINQ - Sub Queries Join / where / group by / order by / select

Tags: sql, linq

The SQL query I prepared is as follows:

```
SELECT 
    r.BookingID, r.FlightDate, r.CarrierCode, r.FlightNo, 
    r.InvoiceNumber, SUM(r.Price) total_price
FROM 
    Reservations r
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT r.BookingID, COUNT(*) cnt
     FROM Reservations r
     GROUP BY r.BookingID) AS all_group ON r.BookingID = all_group.BookingID
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT r.BookingID, COUNT(*) cnt
     FROM Reservations r
     WHERE r.InvoiceNumber IS NOT NULL
     GROUP BY r.BookingID) AS not_null_group ON r.BookingID = not_null_group.BookingID
WHERE 
    all_group.cnt = not_null_group.cnt 
    OR r.InvoiceNumber IS NULL
GROUP BY 
    r.BookingID, r.FlightDate, r.CarrierCode, r.FlightNo, r.InvoiceNumber
ORDER BY 
    r.FlightDate, r.CarrierCode, r.FlightNo, r.InvoiceNumber
```

I want to convert to LINQ but it was too complex for me. Can you guide me?

Many thanks...

Comment: I see repartition and options to optimise this query, so you'd be better to start by asking how to improve this query....

Comment: Perhaps my [SQL to LINQ Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

An exact translation of your existing query would result in the following LINQ:

```cs
from r in Reservations
join all_group in
    (from r in Reservations r
     group by r.BookingID into g
     select new { BookingID: g.Key, cnt = g.Count() })
  on r.BookingID = all_group.BookingID
join not_null_group_joined in 
    (from Reservations r
     where r.InvoiceNumber != null
     group by r.BookingID into g
     select new { BookingID = g.Key, cnt = g.Count() })
  on r.BookingID = not_null_group_joined.BookingID into gj1
  from not_null_group_joined in gj1.DefaultIfEmpty()
where
    all_group.cnt = not_null_group.cnt 
    || r.InvoiceNumber == null
group by
    new { r.BookingID, r.FlightDate, r.CarrierCode, r.FlightNo, r.InvoiceNumber }
    into g
select
    new { g.Key.BookingID, g.Key.FlightDate, g.Key.CarrierCode, g.Key.FlightNo, g.Key.InvoiceNumber,
          total_price: g.Sum(r => r.Price)
        }
order by
    new { g.Key.FlightDate, g.Key.CarrierCode, g.Key.FlightNo, g.Key.InvoiceNumber };
```

However, this is anyway not very efficient. Firstly, the two subqueries could be combined using conditional aggregation and a `HAVING`

```sql
COUNT(*) cnt_all_group, COUNT(InvoiceNumber) cnt_not_null
```

Better yet, eliminate all of it using window functions.

```sql
SELECT 
  r.BookingID,
  r.FlightDate,
  r.CarrierCode,
  r.FlightNo, 
  r.InvoiceNumber,
  CASE WHEN SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY r.BookingID)
          = SUM(COUNT(InvoiceNumber)) OVER (PARTITION BY r.BookingID)
       THEN SUM(r.price)
       ELSE SUM(CASE WHEN r.InvoiceNumber IS NULL THEN r.price END)
       END AS total_price
FROM Reservations r
GROUP BY 
  r.BookingID,
  r.FlightDate,
  r.CarrierCode,
  r.FlightNo,
  r.InvoiceNumber
ORDER BY 
  r.FlightDate,
  r.CarrierCode,
  r.FlightNo,
  r.InvoiceNumber;
```

The equivalent LINQ is a little convoluted to get it to use window functions, but something like this should work:

```cs
from r in Reservations
group by new {
  r.BookingID,
  r.FlightDate,
  r.CarrierCode,
  r.FlightNo,
  r.InvoiceNumber
} into g1
select new {
  g1.BookingID,
  g1.FlightDate,
  g1.CarrierCode,
  g1.FlightNo,
  g1.InvoiceNumber,
  total_price = g1.Sum(r => r.Price),
  null_price = g1.Sum(r => r.InvoiceNumber == null ? r.Price : null),
  all_count = g1.Count(),
  not_null = g1.Count(r => r.InvoiceNumber != null)
}
group by g1.BookingId into g2
from r2 in g2
select new {
  r2.BookingID,
  r2.FlightDate,
  r2.CarrierCode,
  r2.FlightNo,
  r2.InvoiceNumber,
  total_price = g2.Sum(all_count) == g2.Sum(not_null)
    ? r2.total_price
    : r2.null_price
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var allGroupSubQuery = from r in Reservations
                       group r by r.BookingID into grp
                       select new { BookingID = grp.Key, Count = grp.Count() };

var notNullGroupSubQuery = from r in Reservations
                           where r.InvoiceNumber != null
                           group r by r.BookingID into grp
                           select new { BookingID = grp.Key, Count = grp.Count() };

var query = from r in Reservations
            join allGroup in allGroupSubQuery on r.BookingID equals allGroup.BookingID
            join notNullGroup in notNullGroupSubQuery on r.BookingID equals notNullGroup.BookingID into nnGroup
            from notNullGroup in nnGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where allGroup.Count == (notNullGroup?.Count ?? 0) || r.InvoiceNumber == null
            group r by new { r.BookingID, r.FlightDate, r.CarrierCode, r.FlightNo, r.InvoiceNumber } into grouped
            orderby grouped.Key.FlightDate, grouped.Key.CarrierCode, grouped.Key.FlightNo, grouped.Key.InvoiceNumber
            select new
            {
                grouped.Key.BookingID,
                grouped.Key.FlightDate,
                grouped.Key.CarrierCode,
                grouped.Key.FlightNo,
                grouped.Key.InvoiceNumber,
                TotalPrice = grouped.Sum(x => x.Price)
            };

 var result = query.ToList();
```

`allGroupSubQuery` and `notNullGroupSubQuery` correspond to the `inner` and `left join subqueries` in your SQL query. The main query `joins Reservations` with the twosubqueries. Then where clause ensures that either the counts match or the `invoice number is null`. The results are grouped by the necessary fields. Then results are ordered as in your SQL query.